# isolate and rule out some defect blocks

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks

How to isolate and rule out some defect blocks or sector of HDD to keep it functional as well as if it has no defect ?

Comment: `fsck`?  How about at least providing some basic information like what OS you are running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a list of bad blocks using `badblocks`
2. Feed the list to `mkfs.ext4`

Alternatively use `e2fsck`.

More on it here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Badblocks

In a perfect world you'd boot using [HDAT2](https://www.hdat2.com/) - it's a perfect tool for remapping bad blocks which is much better.

If your HDD has started dying I would **not** use it for anything important.